# Why does efficient heap construction require random access?

Tags: c, data-structures

Since you can efficiently construct a heap by **sequentially** iterating through an array:

```
make_heap(priority_queue *q, item_type s[], int n)
{
    int i; /* counter */

    priority_q_init(q);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        priority_q_insert(q, s[i]);
}
```

Part of the priority_q implementation (in case helpful):

```
priority_q_insert(priority_queue *q, item_type x)
{
    if (q->n >= PQ_SIZE)
        printf("warning...overflow");
    else {
        q->n = (q->n) + 1;
        q->q[ q->n ] = x;
        bubble_up(q, q->);
    }
}
```

Why can't you efficiently construct a heap by sequentially iterating through a linked-list ([which it appears you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463514/using-loop-to-traverse-through-linked-list))?

Comment: Where is it claimed that you can't do this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: It depends on the definition of "efficient".

Comment: a few places I've seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090071/heap-sort-a-linked-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885449/heap-sort-using-linked-lists. The claim is also made in Algorithm Design Manual

Comment: This is not about heaps, but the management structures. WHat did you read about priority queues? What is your **specific** problem? You can be expected to atleast had a look at Wikipedia, which already answers your question.

Comment: @Olaf don't have a specific problem, just trying to learn more about algorithms/data-structures. I may be missing something..

Comment: This is not a particularly efficient way to construct a heap. The complexity is O(n log n). There is a way to construct a heap from an array in O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values of a heap are stored in a read-write indexable array. For example, `bubble_up` needs to be able to read and write values in nonsequential order. See Muhammad Ahmad's answer for a more specific example how the heap does nonsequential access.

Thus it's not possible to store and maintain values of a heap in a linked list (or doubly-linked list), because that supports only sequential access. (More specifically: nonsequential access in a linked list is possible, but it's usually too slow. Thus the building and using a heap based on a linked list would be too slow.)

It's possible to convert a linked list to a heap, by starting from an empty heap, iterating over the linked list, and inserting each element in the linked list to the heap. In the end there will be two copies of the values: one in the linked list and one in the heap. The linked list can be deleted then. It's also possible to remove each value during the iteration.

It's not possible to convert a linked list to a heap in place (without copying values or without making it too slow), because the heap needs nonsequential access, and the linked list provides only sequential access efficiently.

Comment: You very well implemet a heap with other data-structures, including a list. It all depends on the access patters. Performance is just one aspect of optimisation.

Comment: @Olaf: I've clarified my answer: it's possible, but too slow.

Comment: I did not say a LL is the only thing. And I explicitly wrote performance is not the only design aspect.

Comment: @Olaf: We agree that linked list and array are not the only options for backing a heap. My answer doesn't contradict this. My answer doesn't talk about this explicitly, because I think it's not relevant enough to the question asked. We agree that performance is not the only design aspect. My answer doesn't contradict this.

Comment: yesss, thank you! was missing the copy/in place distinction

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will answer your question.

The deletion and insertion in heap usually require to compare the data of a node to it's parent or it's child (either left or right or both).

[image]

It's a simple example of an array containing the data of a max heap. (see index 0 is ignored or not used, the root element is stored at index 1, it's left child at index 2, right child at index 3 and so on.)

The benefit of using this kind of implementation is, for a node at index `i`, we can always get it's parent at index `i / 2`, it's left child at index `2 * i` and right child at `2 * i + 1`

When there's a need of comparison of a node with it's parent or child, we can easily get it's parent's or child's index right away. And access directly the node required (as it is an array).

But in case of linked list, you can't directly access it's parent or child, that's linked list is not a fast way of implementing a heap.

Comment: I realize random access is important to the data-structure *underlying* a heap and that an array is great choice here. My question is more about constructing a heap *from* a data-structure without random access (like a linked list)

Comment: What I was trying to say (and obviously failed) was, as I've described, we need random access (i.e. sometimes compare the node's value with parent's and sometimes with child's), and in a data-structure with no random access, it will be slow to access either the child or parent.